# Issue in converting p12 file to pem file

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) for push notifications.

I'd done all the steps in that page. i'd created p12 file and cer file and i converted cer file to pem successfully.

But, while converting p12 file to pem file it's asking for `Enter Import Password`,

Which password should I enter there?

It's returning `Mac verify error: invalid password?` Please assist me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the password you specified when generating the .p12 file in KeyChain.

You entered the password in this step:

> Save the private key as PushChatKey.p12 and enter a passphrase.

Comment: it's working. Can u pl help me, how can I use the commands? `openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
    -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem`, it's returning errors.

Comment: What errors do you get? It could be that a firewall is blocking traffic over port 2195. In any case, this is a different question so you should open a new question.